# Jump between different viewControllers using UIButton?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a button that open another **viewController`(familyView)`** when clicked.
In `familyView` there is another button which suppose to bring me back to the **`mainViewController(ViewController.xib)`** but I don't know how to call the main viewController.

My method to call `familyView`

```
UIViewController* familyView = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"familyView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.view addSubview:familyView.view];
```

I hope you could help on how to call the main `ViewController` ? do I have to use the same method to call it? like this I mean:

```
UIViewController* mainView = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.view addSubview:mainView.view];
```

If yes, is there a better way to implement this? in my demo project, I'm trying to make 7 views full with data and a button to go back and forth.

EDIT:
If I use UIView would that be best for me instead of using different viewControllers with their implementations and interfaces files?
My project will have views, and each view has data on it parsed from a different html page.

Comment: To show the 7 views, take a look at `UINavigationController`, or maybe even `UIPageViewController`. It will probably be of some help.

Comment: Are each of the 7 views the same except for the data they are displaying?  What object are you using to display this data, text view, web view, something else?  Also, do you want to be able to move back and forth between all the views, or just from the main view to any of the other 7 views and then back again to main view?

Comment: I haven't decide the structure yet. It's a demo project so, I want to learn and implement on the go. Mainly, the user should jump between a view to another or as you said, back and forth. I started working with `UINavigationController` as matsr suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two method that can be used.

1. UINavigationController
2. Delegates

From your question it seems that a UINavigationController is the best option but I will show you both.

---

**UINavigationController**

When you load your mainViewController from your app delegate your going to need to wrap it in a nav controller like so:

AppDelegate.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navController;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
@synthesize navController = _navController;
```

//in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
UIViewController *mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];

navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainViewController];

self.window.rootViewController = nav1;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Now in your MainViewController you have the convince of UINavigationController.

When you want to push to a child from a parent you can simply do:

```
ChildViewController *child = [[ChildViewController alloc]...];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:child animated:YES];
```

If you in your ChildViewController and want to go back simply do:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This is the "Drill Down" technique.

*(I know "Drill Down" has more meaning than simply that but it provides a good frame of reference.)*

---

**Delegate**

Now the other method that you have is to setup delegates between the classes. So if your in childView and need to call your parent, you will have a channel to do so.

In your MainViewController.h setup it like so:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

//This is our delegate
@protocol TalkToParentDelegate <NSObject>

//This is our delegate method
- (void)helloParent;
@end

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <TalkToParentDelegate> 
...
..
@end
```

In your MainViewController.m make sure add the delegate method.

```
- (void)helloParent {
  NSLog(@"Hello child, let me do something here");
}
```

In your ChildViewController.h setup it like so:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

//Add header of class where protocol was defined
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface ChildViewController : UIViewController

//Create a property we can set to reference back to our parent
@property (strong, nonatomic) id <TalkToParentDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

Now, in your MainViewController.m , whenever you present your ChildViewController do this:

```
ChildViewController *child = [[ChildViewController alloc]...];

//Set the delegate reference to parent 
child.delegate = self;

//present the view
```

Last but not least, no when you in your child you can call methods on your parent (MainViewController) like so:

[self.delegate helloParent];

---

So here are two methods that you can use.

I would like to note however, you can use these together. Say you had a UINavigationController but still needed a child to talk to its parent, you can setup a delegate so that's possible.

- Hope this helps.

Comment: AWESOME!!! really clear explanation. I appreciate your time doing it. One thing though, what is `nav1.view`? I will be starting to follow your explanation tomorrow after I get back to my code.

Comment: I apologize, it should be "nav1" instead of "nav1.view". :P I fixed the post to resemble the change. Glad I was able to help!

Comment: Followed your guide. Although, you can do most of it from the interface builder, but it's really great to do it programatically. Thanks for your time and answer Cory :)

Comment: @iMohammad Not a problem, glad I could help.